# Can't launch steam

Tags: steam

I get the following response launching steam

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
     unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked back through my terminal history and this is what I did prior to making the post:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam-launcher
```

I then restarted the computer and downloaded a fresh copy of the .deb installer for Steam from https://steamcdna.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb

After installing, it went through the same process and failed to find and install those packages. This time however, the Steam login window popped up (after a lengthy update) and I was able to login.

I am currently downloading a game now to test further. I hope this solution helps.

Update: I still get the error everytime I launch Steam, but Steam still works everytime. I have downloaded and played Borderlands 2 successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in installing Steam using the proprietary drivers downloaded from Nvidia. Instead, I used the proprietary drivers in the "Additional Drivers" application within Ubuntu and installed the latest one listed. Then I ran the following commands pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line before installing steam:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I finally installed Steam with no issues.